# Value Getters - Max call stack exceeded

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to reproduce an Excel spreadsheet of around 100 rows and 16 value columns. Various rows are a sum of other rows, so I'm using valuegetters to set the values. In general, this was working very well. However at the bottom of the table I have multiple rows that depend on other calculated rows. When I add the valuegetters for these, the chain of dependant values becomes large and I've started getting 'max call stack exceeded' on the most chained valuegetters. This happens when these cells come into view - it doesn't matter if there is data in the grid or not as the functions are still being called.

I've considered cell expressions as an alternative, but can't see how to make these reference values in other rows.

I've looked into settimeout in the problem valuegetter to slow things down but haven't got it to work.

Are there any techniques for dealing with this sort of issue?

My valuegetter applies at the column level so it contains various 'if' conditions to determine if the row Id is a calculated one and then does the calculation. If it's not a calculated row, it just returns the unaltered value.

Example:

```
const calculatedRowsValueGetter = (params: ValueGetterParams) => {
    if(params.data.rowkey == "6"){
        let values: string[] = []
        for(let i = 0; i < rowkey6Rows.length; i++){
            values.push(getCalculatedValueFromOtherRow(params, rowkey6Rows[i]))
        }
        return trySumStringArray(values)
    }
    if(params.data.rowkey == "8"){
        let values: string[] = []
        for(let i = 0; i < rowkey8Rows.length; i++){
            values.push(getCalculatedValueFromOtherRow(params, rowkey8Rows[i]))
        }
        return trySumStringArray(values)        
    }
    if(params.data.rowkey == "22"){
        let values: string[] = []
        for(let i = 0; i < rowkey22Rows.length; i++){
            values.push(getCalculatedValueFromOtherRow(params, rowkey22Rows[i]))
        }
        return trySumStringArray(values)  
    }
    if(params.data.rowkey == "36"){
        let values: string[] = []
        for(let i = 0; i < rowkey36Rows.length; i++){
            values.push(getCalculatedValueFromOtherRow(params, rowkey36Rows[i]))
        }
        return trySumStringArray(values)       
    }
}
```

there are around 20 of these conditions. The code within the if statement just calls a function that uses params.api.getValue to get the other row values and then sums the string values.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing a demo of the problem. You can start from any [demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#example-single-row-selection) in the docs ("Open example in Plunker"). Feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) - nesting so deep you hit the call stack limit is probably not the way. Or it might be fine, and you just have a simple bug which is impossible to spot without a demo.

Comment: I'm quite new to AG-Grid, so the question is actually quite general - is there a recommended way of handling situations where you have long chains of dependant cells? The code itself works. The call stack limit is hit when I add a final valuegetter that results in many of the cells becoming dependant on each other. To me. it seems like the valuegetter approach I'm using from the docs doesn't work at this point. Though I'm sure I'm not the first to have needed to do this and there must be a recommended way of dealing with it.

Comment: **A demo is needed.** I can figure out the answer, but I don't just know it off the top of my head, almost nobody will. To solve your question, I would have to repro your problem myself (make a demo), and then fix it. Currently, reproducing the problem is more work than fixing the problem. If you want help, make yourself helpable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others reference, I have resolved this by not using ValueGetters. It appeared that there was too much chaining and between cells and also using functions to get information within a ValueGetters seems to quickly result in the call stack being too large.

A general onCellEdited function with some condition so that it only runs when applicable cells are changed is working well and much more efficient in this case as the calculation is done once when a cell is changed. The function calculated all affected values and then sets the row data.